# Create and send a newsletter from the front-end

Tags: front-end, newsletter

Is there a way that I can allow someone to create and send a newsletter from the front-end, without needing to use the dashboard?

The person who will be doing this task does not need to use the dashboard for other purposes. Learning to navigate the dashboard just for this would be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a special 'contact' type form (like Contact Form 7) that is restricted to the specific user. They could fill out the 'message' area of the form, send it, and the back-end of the form would send it to your subscriber list.

Or the form could send it to you for approval, if needed.  Note that this process is just a one-time thing; no storage of the content other than sending. (Although there are some CF7 add-ins that would allow saving of the content into a database.)

**Added 26 Nov 2017:** Check into the [Email Subscriber and Newsletters plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-subscribers/). It allows you maintain a subscriber list, and send out newsletters with a 'rich text editor' type interface. You can also set it up to send out a canned notice whenever a new post is published. I've just used for the 'new post' notifications, along with the occasional (one-time blast) newsletter. Good plugin, with good support.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But CF7 seems more for sending a simple email with specified fields. I thinking of a newsletter that would be composed over several days and would include multiple sections with photos, etc.

Comment: While true that CF7 can be used for simple forms, my thought was that you could compose the newsletter off-line then paste into the CF7 form. But probably not the best solution for you. My other thought would be something like MailChimp, where you can compose a newsletter and send it to a list. I think that they have a plugin that will allow people to sign up - with the user list maintained in the MailChimp app.

Comment: I definitely need the newsletter to be created in the front-end, without going out to another app. I'm going to look into the plugins that say they can convert selected posts into a newsletter.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz  ....see the addition to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go through for this plugin. I think that use this plugin as per your requirement.

[Sendpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sendpress/)

Comment: This plugin seems the exact opposite of what I am looking for. From the docs, it looks like everything must be done in the dashboard.